# Подмена изображения в браузере

Tags: javascript, webbrowser, плагин

Есть некий сайт, на котором мне, в личных целях необходимо изменить изображение на странице в своем браузере.
Доступ к редактированию страниц сайта нет.
код на сайте:

```
<div id="1"> 
<img id="image" src="p.png" width="1020" height="1270">
 </div>
```

необходимо заменить

```
<div id="1"> 
    <img id="image" src="ss.png" width="1020" height="1270">
     </div>
```

Если не ошибаюсь это можно сделать при помощи JS. Подскажите пожалуйста как именно.
Или как это можно реализовать другим образом без доступа к исходному коду сайта?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зайди на нужный сайт. Потом замени все содержимое адресной строки на это:

```
javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('image').src='ss.png';})();
```

Браузер Chrome, видимо, считает себя умнее всех, и при вставке этой строки из буфера обмена он удаляет префикс "javascript:". Проверь, чтоб при вставке этот префикс сохранился. Если его не будет – допиши руками.

Comment: В FF не работает. В этом контексте оказываются не объявлены document, window, etc.. Вообще не объявлено.

Comment: ни в FF, ни в chrome не работает(

Comment: У меня работает в Хроме. Проверил наличие "javascript:"?
Если все-равно не работает, значит или id не тот, или есть какой-то элемент с этим же id выше по DOM-дереву. Чтобы это проверить, выполни в адресной строке это:

    javascript:(function(){document.getElementById('image').style.outline='#F00 1px dotted';})();

Если красная обводка появится у какого-то другого элемента, значит, так и есть.

Comment: Да, простите, затупил. Спасибо большое! Вы мне жизнь проще сделали)))

Answer (score 0):

Посмотри [stylish](https://www.google.ru/search?q=stylish).

Comment: а что непонятно?

Comment: Вы имели в виду greasemonkey (ну или scriptish)?

Comment: ну конечно ))